# Heroku Push - Error with Git Push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sqlite

I'm getting an error when I try to do a git push to heroku (git push heroku master). I am on cedar stack and my Gemfile specifies sqlite 1.3.5. Here is the error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for sqlite3.h... no
   sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
   or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
   location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
   --with-sqlite3-dir
   --without-sqlite3-dir
   --with-sqlite3-include
   --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
   --with-sqlite3-lib
   --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
   --enable-local
   --disable-local
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_3umr292rjcdek/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_3umr292rjcdek/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
   An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

!
     !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
     !
     !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

Comment: Look at your database.yml. Might be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem I had which caused hours of headaches was with the 'taps' gem.  It was causing pretty much the exact same error for me until I moved it into the 'development' group:

```
group :production do 
  gem 'taps'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Not sure if this is directly applicable to you, but it produced sqlite3 errors until I put taps into :production.  Hopefully it'll help someone.

**EDIT**:  @cloneofsnake:  I don't have enough rep to comment on your answer, but I see you have the 'taps' gem in your Gemfile.  Either get rid of it, or put it in the :production group; taps has some dependencies on sqlite3 apparently.  I had already switched out sqlite3 for pg, but I was getting the same error as you until I moved 'taps' to production.

Answer (score 8):

Heroku is telling you that you can't compile the `sqlite3-ruby` gem on the Heroku platform.

You might want to move the `sqlite3-ruby` gem into a group that isn't installed by default on Heroku.

```
gem "rails"

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
end

group :production do
  gem "pg"
end
```

---

Update: It appears the gem `sqlite3-ruby` is old and the `sqlite3` is the new gem you should use instead.

Comment: This worked for me. Did you make sure to push the changes of the Gemfile to the git repository for your project

Comment: And don't forget to commit any change. It sounds quite obvious, but I started editing and saving and I lost two hours until I realised I hadn't commited anything! Commit!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look which branch you are trying to push.
In my case I was working on dev branch, and trying to push using:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

What git does is pushing my master branch to heroku but my master branch was using sqlite3, causing this weird error.

Try do do:

```
$ git push heroku [name_of_your_branch]:master
```

Comment: It's a good practice also, to aways specify the name of the branch in the right hand-side of the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the necessary gems in production. I recently had this problem myself. Also try using gem 'pg' (POSTGRESQL) instead of sqlite as thats what Heroku uses.

eg:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'carrierwave'
  gem 'rmagick'
  gem 'heroku'
  gem 'git-rails'
  gem "jquery-rails"
  gem 'hoe', '~> 1.5.1'
  gem "RedCloth"
  gem 'i18n'
end
```

Comment: The above error seems to be about sqlite3. As I understand it, group : production do is to enable specific gems for production that are not used on test. In this case would you install a specific version of sqlite3 for production? Or do you mean you would specifiy all installed gems and put them in a production group?

Comment: Right, you get a sqlite error because Heroku uses PostgreSQL. You can develop locally using sqlite and when you push up to Heroku, your migrations are mapped automatically to PostgreSQL. So add gem 'pg' to production, push your app onto Heroku, and then use: "heroku run rake db:migrate" to migrate on Heroku.