# sqlite3 blocking push to Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I've followed all the questions on here already but am STILL getting an error pushing to Heroku.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Remove sqlite3 completely from the gemfile, bundle, git commit and git push to Heroku.
2. Put sqlite3 into group :development, :test do, bundle, git commit and git push to Heroku.
3. Uninstall and reinstall sqlite3 gem, bundle, git commit and git push to Heroku.
4. Remove the Gemlock file, bundle, git commit and git push to Heroku.

Gem file:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'pg'
end
```

Git status is clean.

Git push heroku master failure log is here - http://pastebin.com/K2192h8A

Hopefully someone can let me know what I've done wrong. Thank you.

Comment: So did you try to remove `sqlite3` gem from the **Gemfile**, but the building had been failed anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I ended up rebuilding the whole thing, couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Ok, please redo with the following: make changes in **Gemfike** according yours presented in post, issue `bundle install`, then add into index both **Gemfile**, and **Gemfie.lock**, and push to heroku. and give answer log again here. And show yuor heroku env here.

Comment: I did all those - it doesn't matter, I rebuilt the project and it's been deployed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you mean `rebuilt the project`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up rebuilding the app and it is now deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Always take care to look and make sure you are under the correct git branch!

if you are using

```
git push heroku master
```

then do the command

```
git branch
```

and make sure that you are under the master branch and not elsewhere. You are using git to push to heroku so it make not always be your rails app that is causing the problem. Be sure to

```
git add.
```

and

```
git commit -m "comment"
```

before looking at your rails app for mistakes.

this question solved this for me.
[Heroku Push - Error with Git Push to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050770/heroku-push-error-with-git-push-to-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

next time you buil a new app to get rid of all the fuss you must do the following: `rails new -d postgresql` ,if u don't have heroku addons installed do this `heroku addons:add heroku_postgresql:hobby-dev`
next `heroku addons | grep POSTGRES` and finally `heroku run rake db:migrate`
that should be it